# Need to do compare without functions by using 3 variables on

Tags: c++, function, variables

Need to do compare without functions. I gotta do compare by using function just once and use no more 3 variables. Task that I got: need to tabulate (A to B, with h step) and show local minimum by “*”
——————————

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clocale"
#include "cmath"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// ------------------------- f(x) = x*sin(3*x) - 1  -------------------
double f(double x){
    return x*sin(3*x) - 1;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");

    double A,B;
    double h;

    // ------------------    ---------------------
    cout << "A = ";
    cin >> A;

    cout << "B = ";
    cin >> B;

    cout << "h = ";
    cin >> h;

    // ------------------------------------------------------

    cout.setf(ios_base::fixed);
    cout.precision(4);

    for (double k=A; k<=B; k+=h){
        if (f(k - h) >= f(k) && f(k + h) >= f(k)){
            cout << "*";
        }
        else{
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "x = " << k << "  y = " << f(k) << "\n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

 }
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what is being asked here. Can you please write a pseudocode explanation of what you need to be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I guess right what you want to do. For each `f(x)` you want to compare that value to `f(x-h)` and `f(x+h)` to see if `f(x)` is a local minimum. You seem to have something, but you are recalculating `f(x-h)`, `f(x)` and `f(x+h)` every time you use the value, when in fact on each iteration you only need to compute a single new value.

Just remember previous values. Note that the first point you can compare previous and next value is `A+h`, hence we start with

```
auto current = f(A+h);
auto previous = f(A);
auto next = f(A+2*h);
if (do the comparison of current vs previous and next) print something
// now the loop
for (double x = A+2*h; x < B; x+=h){
    previous = current;
    current = next;      // in the first iteration this is f(A+2*h)
    next = f(x+h);
    if (do the comparison of current vs previous and next) print something
}
```

Note that now in each iteration only the `next` value is calculated, while `current` and `previous` are already known from the iteration before.

Comment: Of course you're now using 6 variables, not 3. The question specifically said 3.

Comment: @MSalter hum you are demanding :P Have to take a break, but will fix that later

Comment: @MSalters no idea how to do it with only 3, you need at least `h` and `B` for step size and stop condition which leaves only a single one for all the rest (unless using some cheating)

Answer (score 0):

since you are trying to find local minima then you should try following code. this is exactly as you wanted but more robust.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clocale"
#include "cmath"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// ------------------------- f(x) = x*sin(3*x) - 1  -------------------
double f(double x){
    return x*sin(3*x) - 1;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

bool is_minima(double a, double b, double c){
    if(a > b && c > b){
         return true;
    else
 return false;
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");

    double A,B;
    double h;

    // ------------------    ---------------------
    cout << "A = ";
    cin >> A;

    cout << "B = ";
    cin >> B;

    cout << "h = ";
    cin >> h;

    // ------------------------------------------------------

    cout.setf(ios_base::fixed);
    cout.precision(4);

    for (double k=A; k<=B; k+=h){
        if (is_minima(f(k-h),f(k),f(k+h))){
            cout << "*";
        }
        else{
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "x = " << k << "  y = " << f(k) << "\n";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

 }
```